# How to Mass Import Historical Emails into Salesforce?

Tags: email, migration, import

I'm deploying a new SF org.
I've got hundreds of past email threads with customers I want to "import" to SF and have these emails appear as activities under the Account/Case record.
Is there any way to achieve that?

I thought of using email-to-salesforce and FW the emails to the designated email address but the email will be filed under unresolved items instead of under the Account

Comment: are those emails in your mail client or those are registered in your previous CRM?

Comment: in my mail client

Comment: How comfortable would you be with the REST API? Or would you stick to GUI?

Comment: very comfortable

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you need to include a reference to the Account or Case you want the activity history to be associated with.

So when you forward the existing emails you need to put `ref: 001D0000000HQZy` into either the email subject line or body. Here 001D0000000HQZy is the 15 character Salesforce Id for an Account. You can get the required Ids from the URLs when viewing individual records.

Without that reference Salesforce will add the emails to the "My Unresolved Items" page.

See the [Adding Email with Email to Salesforce](https://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/email_my_email_2_sfdc_using.htm) documentation.

Failing that, you could use something like the Data Loader to directly create the required Task records from a CSV export of the emails.

Comment: The Case "ref:" is different from its Salesforce id.  Here's the formula:  "ref:00D"&MID(Id,4,1)&RIGHT($Organization.Id, 4) &"."& LEFT(Id,4)&RIGHT(Id,5) &":ref"

Comment: Actually, RIGHT(...,5) won't work forever... it's stripping out the middle zeros, so a proper solution is to see which character has a significant (non-zero) character.